# Determine type of vehicle used for travelling

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

Is there a way using one of the google maps apis to determine the most probably used vehicle type for a recorded route?

For example is there an automated way to determine if I‘m travelling by train? Or do I have to implement that myself?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the [`transit_mode`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#optional-parameters) to indicate the vehicle type that the calculated route should prefer.

But what you're looking for is information for the vehicle type that is most probably used for a given route, which is not currently something that the API provides.

I recommend you file a feature request for this in Google's [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/) so that Google's Tech Engineers can consider implementing this. For now, you would need to implement this yourself indeed.

Hope this helps!